# I have created a REST API using Django.How do I now use this API for a site?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have successfully created an API for a blog using Django but how do I use it to create a website including the HTML and CSS, all the tutorials point towards creating an API not towards **using/utilizing** it.

Any set of tutorials or any guideline is highly appreciated.

Thanks!!

Comment: Seems a bit strange to have created an API without any kind of use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply write your HTML and get your api data with jquery ajax calls.
i.e  `$.get(URL,callback);` `$.post(URL,data,callback);`
Here `URL` is your api endpoint and `callback` is userdefined function to handle api response.

Ex.

```
 $.get("/blog/posts/", function(data, status) {
   alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
 });
```

Comment: So do I need to  deploy the API first on the web, because the URL can't be from the local development server which Django offers.

Comment: If you are developing you frontend in your local system, then you need not to deploy. You can just run in your loacl say (127.0.0.1:8000) then you can use urls like `http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog/posts/` in your ajax requests